# S3 size limit on ApiGateway created by CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway, aws-cloudformation

I have a cloud formation template that defines a new api gateway:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: API for getting planetary info
Resources:
  PlanetsApi:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
    Properties:
      Name: "Planets API"
```

I have CodePipeline set up to create this as a change set and then execute the change set.

When the change set executes, it fails with the following error:

```
13:55:28 UTC-0400   CREATE_FAILED   AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi PlanetsApi S3 object size exceeds limit of 2 MB
```

I don't know where this limit is coming from, or why anything is being uploaded to S3. Google searches are turning up no useful information. Curiously, if I create the change set and execute through the CloudFormation console, I don't get any errors.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. And wow, I realized when I use `aws cloudformation package`, it creates a `BodyS3Location` with its properties (`Bucket` and `key`) under where I define my `Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi`. This happens, even though I had not defined such parameters earlier in my template, before being processed by `cloudformation package`. This, then causes the error.

What I did to tackle this issue:

1. Let the `CodePipeline` to run, and fail (with the error)
2. Go to the **AWS Console**, find the failed stack, and expand **Template**
3. Find the lines in which `BodyS3Location` and its parameters are generated (for me they were in lines 22 to 24)
4. Add a command in `buildspec.yml` to delete these lines, after the
   package command (example below)

   - `aws cloudformation package --s3-bucket some-s3bucket --template-file ./template.yml --output-template-file ./packaged-template.yml`
   - `sed --in-place '22,24d' packaged-template.yml`
5. `commit` and `push` to repo again
6. It must work now!

**Note:** This is not the best solution, this issue must be solved, from **AWS** end!

---

**UPDATE:**

It is something to do with the AWS CLI version. Try installing this version before running the `cloudformation package` command (in your `CodeBuild`), and you should be good to go.

```
pip install awscli==1.11.37
```